# UnderscoreJS find-and-replace

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

In my application, I have a very large array of objects on the front-end, and these objects all have some kind of long ID under the heading ["object_id"]. I'm using UnderscoreJS for all my manipulations of this list. This is a prototype for an application that will eventually be handling most of this effort on the backend.

Merging the list is a big part of the application's requirement. See, the list that I work with initially will have many distinct objects with identical object_ids. Initially I was merging them all in one go with a groupBy and a map-reduce, but now the requirements have changed and I'm merging them one at a time (about a second apart, to simulate a stream of input) into a initially empty array.

My naive implementation was something like this:

```
function(newObject, objects) {
    var obj_id = newObject["object_id"]; //id of object to merge, let's say
    var tempObject = null;
    var objectToMerge = _.find(objects,
        function(obj) {
            return obj_id == obj["object_id"];
        });
    if (objectToMerge) {
        tempObject = merge(objectToMerge, newObject);
        objects = _.reject(objects, /*same function as findWhere*/ );
    } else {
        tempObject = newObject;
    }
    objects.push(tempObject);
    return objects;
}
```

This is ridiculously more efficient than before, when I was remerging from the mock data "source" array every time a new object was supposed to be pushed, so it's down from what I think was O(N^2) at least to O(N), but N here is so large (for JavaScript, anyway!) I'd like to optimize it. Currently worst case, where the object_id is not redundant, is the entire list is traversed twice. So what I'd like is to do a find-and-replace, an operation which would return a new version of the list, but with the merged object in place of the old one.

I could do a map where the iterator returns a new, merged object iff the object_id is the same, but that doesn't have the short-circuit evaluation that _.find has, which means the difference between having a worst-case runtime and having that be the default runtime, and doesn't easily account for pushing the object if there wasn't a match.

I'd also like to avoid mutating the original array in place. I know objects.push(tempObject) does that very thing, but for data-binding reasons I'm ignoring that and returning the mutated list as though it were new.

It's also unavoidable that I'll have to check the array to see if the new object was merged or whether it was appended. Using closures I could keep track of a flag to see if the merge happened, but I'm trying to be as idiomatically LISPy as possible for my own sanity. Also, past a certain point, most objects will be merged, so extra runtime overheard for adding new items isn't a huge problem, as long as it is only incurred when it has to happen.

Comment: Does the order of the elements matter?

Comment: No, they're sorted later, before display, according to user input.

Comment: Then I would prefer using an object instead of an array.

Comment: Well, I mean, at other times the order of the elements matters, but not for the sake of this part of the algorithm.

Comment: When you want to display, you can construct a new array and sort that?

Comment: Maybe I should hear your case as to why you'd prefer an object. 

Also, the static data that I'm seeding from is currently formatted as JS array, and it's huge and I wouldn't want to try to process it into being an object

Comment: If you just want to improve the performance of find and replace, I would say object lookup would be the best.